# Is it possible to use a liquid cooler in reverse inside a sealed computer case to cool and circulate air for cooling the motherboard?

Tags: cooling, temperature, computer-building

I am interested in building a sealed computer which will be running inside a very dusty environment. I intend on sealing the case to prevent dust from getting in and cool the CPU, VRM and GPU using liquid cooling. The liquid cooling pipes will pass through to the outside of the case where the radiator is going to be placed.

My concerns is that other heat generating components on the motherboard will eventually increase the temperature inside the case to a level which will cause system instability and probably reduce the lifetime of the computer.

In order to fix this, I was thinking of placing the heat exchanger of another liquid cooler inside the case and use it in reverse: have cooled liquid from the externally mounted cooler pass through the internal cooler and have it absorb the heat from the air inside the case which will then be circulated over the motherboard and cool it.

I assume the theory is correct but I am worried if the efficiency of the coolers make it feasible, hence my question. Is it even worth piecing together a test rig to try it out?

Comment: And how would you use the liquid cooler in reverse?  Also, it is possible but it would be really inefficient and totally not worth piecing things together as the result is failure (simple reason, coolers already have a medium efficiency in taking the heat generated, air is a bad conductor of heat as well)

Comment: Normally the cooling liquid passes through the CPU block, gets warmed as it absorbs the heat from and cools the CPU and is then pumped through the heat exchanger which has cool air forced through it by a fan. I want to do the opposite: connect output of the cooler to the internal heat exchanger so that it receives cold liquid instead of warm liquid -> have the fan blow the air warmed up by the motherboard through the heat exchanger -> the warm air gets cooled by the cold liquid. Hot air on one side, cold(er) air on the other.

Comment: The problem you would run into is the fact that you will create a convection current as there is no place for the hot air to go.

Comment: The fans would be really inefficient for blowing the cool air you would obtain from the cold liquid.

Comment: Also by application of thermodynamics, it is easy to transmit hot stuff rather than cold stuff(air in this case) because the loss in heatness/coldness is very high as it is directed proportional to square of distance

Comment: I was thinking of separating the case into two chambers connected by two ports. These ports would be placed such that for air to travel from one port to the other it would have to pass over the motherboard. The heat exchanger will be placed at one of these ports and a simple fan on the other port.

Comment: A better solution would be using an air conditioner duct as using only air will be more efficient as opposed to air-water interface.

Comment: That would make it rather difficult to move around but it does mean that I probably won't need to water cool at all

Comment: https://youtu.be/RrJreUX3TCk watch this video, it is the third part also see the first and second one to get an idea, seems similar. Suits your requirements.

Comment: @Valay_17 they submerged the entire PC in mineral oil. Seems a little overkill. I'd think making the case air tight (or rather "dust tight") is easier than making it water tight.

Comment: @K7AAY I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Why would I want the CPU block to receive heat? Perhaps you misread my question but I specified I intend to cool the CPU and GPU using the conventional liquid cooling method.

Comment: @user550628 Yes but think about the efficiency and the really low amount of maintenance required as well.

Comment: It would definitely be more compact and easier to design but I'm wondering if the thermal mass of the mineral oil will make it difficult to cool once it starts to really warm up. Then again, I suppose the CPU and the GPU are the components that generate the most heat and the liquid cooler can easily handle those.

Comment: You could use water instead.

Comment: The only way I'd do that is if the water was distilled. For a closed water cooling circuit that may be suitable but I'm not sure how much time the water will remain distilled if I submerge the entire PC in it.

Comment: There are many challenges but the outcome is really good.